# How do I keep a cloth sim object inflated?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm modelling a bed for a personal project and I wanted to make a duvet or puffy blanket for it, I've tried using cloth sim or Model Cloth (Used this video for example but mine doesnt seem to work https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=34&v=qHEWsNYdGag&feature=emb_logo) and I cant seem to get the look I want. Any tips or ideas?

Comment: this is the tutorial you need to follow: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjEaoINr3zgGgS-N9Ews90bDAYYLoP0NO

Answer (score 1):

For 2.8+ versions use the cloth *Pressure* property under the *Physics* properties of the cloth object. Enable it and add a value that suits your particular object.

Make sure the geometry has enough subdivisions for an acceptable effect, and little enough that it get usable performance.

[image]